# i face IDE error in android studio flutter ,please solve this

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1rXt.png)]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/52gGB.png)

As you see above images , you can see the error in which i am not able to connect AVD and i also cannot run through the USB debugging Sometimes it;s show Android SDK not found but i can run in windows and web .

I also face the following error when i run flutter doctor

````dart
Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path "/path/to/android/studio".
Please verify that the path is correct and update it by running this command: flutter config --android-studio-dir
'<path>'

To have flutter search for Android Studio installations automatically, remove
the configured path by running this command: flutter config --android-studio-dir ''


PS C:\Users\zeeshan faiyaz\OneDrive\Desktop\flutter\miniland> flutter doctor
Could not find the Android Studio installation at the manually configured path "/path/to/android/studio".
Please verify that the path is correct and update it by running this command: flutter config --android-studio-dir
'<path>'

To have flutter search for Android Studio installations automatically, remove
the configured path by running this command: flutter config --android-studio-dir ''```

i try to run my flutter app but it shows ide error
````

Comment: did you run ```flutter config --android-studio-dri``` like it is telling you to? you have to tell flutter where android studio so that is has the android apk to run properly for android